# Is it possible to load xml files of name different from spring.application.name using cloud config server?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration, config, configserver

Assuming `my spring.application.name = test` , I know that its possible to load property files with name test.properties, `test-<profile>`.properties and the common application.properties from the cloud config server. But is it possible to have , say a file called `abc.xml`,to be loaded using the config server? Can we keep this file in a folder in the class path of the config server and load it somehow?